# JDA ChannelManager setname Channel view online stats

Tags: java, discord-jda

After joining discord, the channel should refresh and show the new number of players online. After executing twice, the channel does not refresh again.

```java
public void onGuildMemberJoin(@Nonnull GuildMemberJoinEvent event) {
    Guild guild = event.getGuild();
    long online = guild.getMembers().stream()
            .filter(member -> 
                    !member.getOnlineStatus().equals(OnlineStatus.OFFLINE))
            .count();
    VoiceChannel channel = event.getGuild().getVoiceChannelById(742890118943080480L);
    channel.getManager().setName("Online: " + online).queue();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discord doesn't want bots to update channels this often. Channel names are not supposed to be used to display statistics like this. They recently introduced a 2 / 10 minute rate limit on this update process.

This means you cannot update the channel name (or topic) more than twice every 10 minutes.